# Xamarin froms Gelocator showing wrong current location

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using Geolocator plugin for getting current device location but it shows wrong result. Now I am in India but it shows San Francisco. Can you please suggest what wrong I have done. Thanks in advance.

code :

```
var locator = CrossGeoLocator.Current;

locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(1000);
```

When I verified finally getting coordinates it's belongs to San Francisco.

Comment: Are you running this on a simulator? If so you can change the location the simulator uses by going up to Debug > Location.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Yes I am working on ios simulator in xamarin studio. how can change simulator location hear. I can't find any location change option hear,

Comment: Like I said, it's up in the menu bar under Debug > Location in the iOS Simulator.

Comment: Thanks steven I have catched finally. Is there any posibility to get current location without mentioning any coordinates in debug menu options.

Comment: Not in the iOS simulator since that runs on your laptop that doesn't actually have a GPS module.

Comment: okay steven, Thanks  for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running this on a simulator you can change the location the simulator uses by going up to Debug > Location. You can't get your actual location in the iOS simulator since that runs on your laptop that doesn't actually have a GPS module.